# Xcode Bug Fixed?: Unable to look up screen scale / Unexpected physical screen orientation

Tags: mac, ios, xcode, simulator

I did some digging but with zero luck. Does anyone know of a fix yet for this seemingly common Xcode/Simulator bug?

It seemed to cause a lot of lag in performance, so it's not just some random jargon in the console that's bothersome. I read that it won't happen with a physical device, but I would still like to use the simulator.
Thanks very much in advance!

**"Unable to look up screen scale"**

**"Unexpected physical screen orientation"**

- Xcode 10.2.1 (tried reinstalling it as well, by dragging Xcode from Applications to Trash and reinstalling on the App Store)
- Simulator 10.2.1, occurs on all phones I tried: SE, Xs, Xr, Xs Max
- MacOS Mojave 10.14.4

[image: Here's a screenshot of my console and simulator]

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode, Product - Scheme - Edit Scheme，choose ’Run’ at the left，then add 'OS_ACTIVITY_MODE ' whose value is 'disable' in ’Environment variables’.
you chould try this method.

Comment: Thanks! I’ll give it a shot